# Can't check text copied to clipboard with Firefox with Cypress

Tags: javascript, firefox, cypress

Can't copy text to clipboard and verify it using Firefox browser.

In chrome the following code is working, however in Firefox it throws an error:

```
No handler registered for: 'remote:debugger:protocol'
```

And here is the code which is working for Chrome:

```
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol',{
        command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
        params:{
            permissions:['clipboardReadWrite','clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
            origin:this.urlvalue
        },
    }))
    cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
    .then((clip) => clip.readText())
    .should('contain', 'test')
}
```